# writing to a temp file in python with a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code in *Example 1* below writes a single line into a temp file. I was expecting it to write multiple lines into the temp file as is shown in *Example 2*, which writes 94 lines to the console.  Cause the `temp.write(shift(alphabet,i))` is in the same place of the loop as `print(shift(alphabet,i))`.

Why?

**Example 1**

```py
import tempfile, os

alphabet = b'!"\'#$%&()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'

def shift(seq, n):
    n = n % len(seq)
    return seq[n:] + seq[:n]

def alphatemp():
    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    print("Created file is:", temp)
    print("Name of the file is:", temp.name)
    try:
        for i in range(len(alphabet)):
            open(temp.name)
#            os.write(temp.name, shift(alphabet,i))

            temp.write(shift(alphabet,i))
            temp.seek(0)

        print(temp.read())
    finally:
#        os.close(temp.name)
        temp.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    alphatemp()
```

**Example 2**

```py
import tempfile, os

alphabet = b'!"\'#$%&()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'

def shift(seq, n):
    n = n % len(seq)
    return seq[n:] + seq[:n]

temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

print("Created file is: ", temp)
print("Name of this file is: ", temp.name)

try:
    for i in range(len(alphabet)):
#        temp.write(shift(alphabet,i))
        print(shift(alphabet,i))
    
#        print(temp.read())
finally:
    temp.close()
```

Comment: `temp.seek(0)`: every iteration of the loop, you move the file pointer back to the start of the file, overwriting the previous line. Remove / uncoment this line, and you're good to go (with the possible exception that you may need to add newlines; you'll find out along the way).

Comment: For that matter, why not use `with open(temp.name, "a") as f:`?

Comment: Also note that `open(temp.name)` is superfluous. You're creating a _second_ handle to the file, and then immediately discarding it.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal `temp` is already an open file-like object. There's no need to open it again, just `with temp:` should do it

Comment: Given the line `print(temp.read())`, you probably intended to seek to position 0 *outside* of the loop. So you should dedent the `temp.seek(0)` line. Then again, since this print line is just a debugging line (I assume), writing to the file, closing it, then opening it for reading, is probably better overall.

Comment: @Brian completely read over that, you're absolutely correct.

Comment: @9769953: I want temp.seek(0) in the loop I think because I want to print 94 lines into the temp file.

Comment: Please read the first comment, and think carefully about what `temp.seek(0`) is doing, and what is happening to the file. It's definitely not what you want if you want 94 separate lines in the temporary file.

Comment: @9769953: ahh okay. it was over writing its self. It works at the end of the for loop. aka after the for loop